# Why is pandas not reading the data properly when I filter?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, pandas, filtering

I'm working with a database that shows student suspension rates for schools in Los Angeles County. I want to break down the data with pandas into variables representing each school district. Each school district has four rows of data.

But when I go to create a variable, it shows zero rows when I type in the name of the variable .info()

And when I try to create a variable for the Compton Unified School District, for example, I ask it to return values == "Compton Unified", which is exactly how it's entered in the database, it says "False" for every single row, even though there are four rows where I should be getting "True".

Why would it not read the values properly? This is the code. I'm working with a csv called "suspensions." There are four rows under the school_district column called "Compton Unified", representing the data for the Compton Unified School District. But when I run this code, I get a list showing all the rows are "False," when four of them should say true.

```
compton_suspensions = suspensions.school_district == "Compton Unified"

compton_suspensions.head(120)
```

Comment: Show us your code! It's difficult to answer if we don't know what you've tried so far.

Comment: Might be data issue, e.g. stray whitespace characters. It can also be encoding issue. One thing to try is whether .str.contains() work on, say, "Compton", or "Comp". Then try to work backwards from there

Comment: can you show the data beside